# unable to check out different repo from azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

[image]

how to checkout from different repo, below is the code I have in resources / repository section. currently getting the below error

The repository qp-EAR-AA-8643 in project ea-quality-process-improvement could not be retrieved. Verify the name and credentials being used.

[image]

this is how I am trying to checkout the code

```
      - checkout: QPExpressDestinationRepo 
        persistCredentials: true
        clean: true
```

I have applied the answers given below but I am getting this error.I gave the link of repo which I am trying to connect (QPExpressDestinationRepo)

[image]

Comment: Do you need whole different repository or just merely single file (or several files) from that?

Comment: See my answer, the issue should comes from the service connection of your original organization. :)

Comment: @zbynour i am trying to checkout the whole repo

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT Thanks for your time...I am getting the above issue after applying your answer. any specific access I need in the repo which I am trying to checkout?

Comment: @SheebaCross Hi, I notice the url you are using is git clone url? Back to see my answer, it should be organization URL(`https://dev.azure.com/<Organization Name>`). :)

Comment: So another way could be to clone git repository in custom script (e.g. inline bash script (`job`, `steps` and `task` with inline script) where you can simply type git commands).

Comment: Hi, any update of this issue, have you checked my updated answer? :)

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue:

[image]

This issue needs to make sure two things to make the service connection be able to be used in the 'resources.repositories.repository'.

**1, Please make sure the service connection type is 'Azure Repos/Team Foundation Server'.**

[image]

**2, Please make sure the 'Authentication method' is 'Token Based Authentication'.**

[image]

This is my pipeline YAML definition, and it works fine:

```
trigger:
- none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: QPExpressDestinationRepo
    type: git
    name: xxx/xxx
    endpoint: TestOrgBowman #Also need to check common git connection type.
    ref: refs/heads/main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: QPExpressDestinationRepo
  persistCredentials: true
  clean: true
- script: ls
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

This is the structure of the repository in another organization:

[image]

This is the pipeline result from the original organization:

[image]

See **[Official document of Repository resource definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#repository-resource-definition)**